# Python Database connection for mariadb using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mariadb

I am new to python. I am trying to make a database connection using python to mariadb database which is hosted on my local network. I am using sqlalchmemy to make a connection. 
But facing some errors
this is my code

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('MariaDBDialect://username:password@host:port/databasename')
```

The error I am getting is

```
`Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:MariaDBDialect`
```

If anyone knows what I am doing wrong please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I was just confused by this topic and created a short [blog post about connector strings](https://martin-thoma.com/sql-connection-strings/).

The following solution works for Python 3:

### requirements

```
pip install SQLAlchemy
pip install PyMySQL
```

### Code

```
import sqlalchemy

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql+pymysql://user:password@host/dbname'

# Test if it works
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, echo=True)
print(engine.table_names())
```

Yes, it really is "mysql" and not "mariadb".

Comment: I started using pymysql which was super easy to make a connection @Martin Thoma .

Comment: As of the past month, the mariadb org has released a native mariadb connector package so you don't need to use pymysql anymore.  It is DBAPI compliant and can be used as a drop-in replacement.

Answer (score 8):

Just use mysql+mysqldb instead of MariaDB engine, they work pretty much similar.

```
create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://username:password@host:port/databasename')
```

**Update:**
You also should install mysql-python for python2

```
pip install mysql-python
```

Or mysqlclient for python3:

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

Comment: If my running using this I am getting this error                               
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

Comment: then just run 'pip install mysqlclient' for python3 or 'pip install mysql-python' for python2. this will install all the dependencies

Comment: tried pip install mysqlclient but got this                      error Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-install-Xhd1Qu/mysqlclient/

Comment: your python's setuptools are probably out of date.
please try running 'pip install --upgrade setuptools'

Comment: no luck even after upgrading the tools same error as above

Comment: This is probably worth to look for fix of this error since this is not related to only mysql module but python internal libs.

Answer (score 4):

Starting from SQLAlchemy 1.4.0b1 you can use mariadb dialect and and native mariadb connector. Use the following url scheme: `'mariadb+mariadbconnector://'`.

Prerequisites:

- SQLAlchemy 1.4.0b1 could be installed through **pip install --pre sqlalchemy**
- MariaDB Connector/Python should be also installed. It has its own system dependency, MariaDB Connector/C.

Answer (score 2):

As Stepan mentioned, the MariaDB dialect is now directly supported within SQLAlchemy, which allows you to use the official MariaDB Python connector.

For example:

```py
import sqlalchemy

# Define the MariaDB engine using MariaDB Connector/Python
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mariadb+mariadbconnector://app_user:Password123!@127.0.0.1:3306/database_name")
```

For more details on this you can check out an official MariaDB blog post on the subject here -> https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/using-sqlalchemy-with-mariadb-connector-python-part-1/

And also a deeper dive into setting up object relationships in part 2 -> https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/using-sqlalchemy-with-mariadb-connector-python-part-2/